# Should I give a time range or specifc time when asked for interview availability?

Tags: professionalism, interviewing, email

I was mailed by an HR asking for availability for a phone interview and I mailed him the exact date and time. Should I reply back giving a particular date and a  time range when I'll be free, so that the HR can make a call as per his schedule.

I feel that it will look like I presumed that HR would be free at the time I had given, instead of asking his availability or so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't complicate myself much on this one. I'd say you reply back with something like:

> Regarding my last email, I am also available on [days] between [time interval] in case the proposed date was not a good option.
>
> Otherwise, I am OK with the time and date already suggested.

For future reference, it would be better if you give a time interval instead of an exact date, so both parts can accommodate to their schedules.